# word how to make a header1 after a textfield

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I have a page that contains the name of the chapter, which is header1 style, and after it I inserted a text field in order to add a quote. so here is what my page looks like:

[image]

I was advised to add the quote **before** the header, so I want to move the header down, I know I can keep pressing enter, but that sounds like not the professional way. can you help me here?

Comment: Why are you adding a text field? Just paste your quote text in a paragraph before the header, and then format the quote as appropriate.

Comment: @DavidPostill Okay I got you, it is a good idea, but then I will need to keep pressing enter if I want to make my quote not in the first line, right?

Comment: Have you looked at adjusting the space before/after the text in its paragraph properties (right-click menu)?  Also, just out of curiosity, why would you have a page break immediately following the header?

Comment: @sarah You can also put the quote in a [Text Box](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-text-box-2f188ec1-b14c-4026-8e92-6417d983dc18) and position the text box where you want it to appear.